# Why am I getting 'not defined error' attempting to use python-fstab module?

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to python, and would like to use python-fstab to read/write the file.  I'm finding I can't seem to use it properly ( basic skills issue I suspect, but searches here and in google have been fruitless).  The readme at https://github.com/ProteinSimple/python-fstab isn't helping me here.

So, here are my steps:

```
~/work/python$ sudo pip install fstab

Downloading/unpacking fstab
  Downloading fstab-1.4.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package fstab

Installing collected packages: fstab
  Running setup.py install for fstab

Successfully installed fstab
Cleaning up...
```

then go into python shell:

```
~/work/python$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 13 2014, 11:03:55) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import fstab
>>> fstab = Fstab()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Fstab' is not defined
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',    '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode']
>>> dir(fstab)
['Fstab', 'Line', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__',   '__package__', 'os', 're', 'tempfile']
```

So it's in my $PYTHONPATH

Why am I getting not defined error?

tia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fstab` != `Fstab`. The first is the module name, which you've already imported, and the second probably a class name. So you should use `fstab.Fstab` or include first `from fstab import Fstab`.